# Tsql csv comma delim quote qual

Tags: ssis, flat-file, quote, qualifiers, csv-import

I have a csv file with 1 field that requires Quote Qualifier because it contains comma's.
Building this into an SSIS package flat file import task.
This field also contains extra quotes that I need to import into the field3.
Bulk Copy import will have the same issue when separating. Anyone run into this issue? Researching, I could not find much to go on. TIA

Field1,Field2,"This Field3 is all "one" and commas",Field4,Field5

Comment: Write a proper title, question and add examples of the actual data instead of describing it.

Comment: If the *actual* file contains `"This Field3 is all "one" and commas"`, it's not valid CSV. The [CSV spec, RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html) says `If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.` CSV may be lax but not *that* lax. The program that created this file needs to fix it. A *very* good idea would be to change the field quote to a different character, eg `'` or something that won't appear inside the fields, eg `|` or `§`